# VBA Find Closest Value

Tags: excel, vba, logic

I have a spreadsheet with 12 columns (3 columns apart) listing a bunch of numerical values. I am wondering what would be the best way to sort through these to find the cell that has the value closest to 0.5.

Would a Vlookup work effectively in this situation or am I better off looping through the values with some sort of test?

Comment: Are the numbers unique, no duplicates?  And when you say "Cell" what do you really want to return in the end?

Comment: Simplest way w/o macros would probably be to filter > sort each column and check the numbers

Comment: @ScottCraner the cells should all be unique, but it is possible that some values are off by 0.01. In the end i need to return the value and the value in the column to its left for each of the 12 columns.

Comment: @Kubie this wouldn't work as I would be pulling in numerous data sets and it would simply take too long

Comment: So you would expect 2 results the number and the cell to the left from each column of data?  So 24 total results?

Comment: @ScottCraner exactly

Comment: By 3 columns apart do you mean, for example, start at col 1, then check col 4, then col 7, etc. ?

Comment: @Kubie Column D, G, J etc... hold the value i need to test for and C, F, I etc... have the corresponding value i would need to pull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to place this in a new module in VBE editor and just specify your sheet name below in the code. It prints the results for each column 2 rows below the bottom of each column.

```
Sub checker()

Dim row As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim col As Integer
Dim dif As Double
Dim minRow As Long: minRow = 1
Dim startRow

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter your sheet name")

' change 1 to 2 below if your first row is a header not a data value
startRow = 1

' starting at col D
For col = 4 to 4 + (3*12) Step 3

    dif = Abs(.Cells(startRow, col) - .5)
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

    For row = startRow To lastRow
        If Abs(.Cells(row, col).Value - .5) < dif Then
            dif = Abs(.Cells(row, col).Value - .5)
            minRow = row
        End If
    Next

    ' print result at bottom of ea row
    .Cells(lastRow + 2, col).Value = "Row: " & minRow & ", dif: " & dif & ", value: " & .Cells(minRow, col).Value

Next

End With

End Sub
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
Dim number(100) As Double
Dim target(100) As Range
Dim currcell As Range
Dim currline As Integer
Dim currcolumn As Integer

For currcolumn = 3 To 15 Step 3
    number(currcolumn) = Cells(currcolumn, 2)
    Set target(currcolumn) = Cells(currcolumn, 2)
    For currline = 2 To 20
        If Abs(Cells(currline, currcolumn) - 0.5) < number(currcolumn) Then
            number(currcolumn) = Abs(Cells(currline, currcolumn) - 0.5)
            Set target(currcolumn) = Cells(currline, currcolumn)
        End If
    Next currline
    MsgBox "column: " & currcolumn & " number:" & target(currcolumn) & " at line: " & target(currcolumn).Row
Next currcolumn

End Sub
```

Comment: would I be able to pull the row number for each of these values? I need to get the row for each 12 columns so I would need 12 target ranges in this case...or add 3 to the col number each time

Comment: When I wrote this I thought you wanted one single answer, not one for each row. I will rewrite the code in this answer to help with this problem.

Comment: Now the code works for every 3rd column (adjustable) of a predefined array. The output is via MsgBox, but you would probably prefer to output the results into a cell.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B2:B21)/(AGGREGATE(15,6,ABS($C$2:$C$21-0.5),1)=ABS($C$2:$C$21-0.5)),1))
```

And drag over.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @scottcraner but could you explain how this works please?

Comment: It finds the where the abs of the number minus .5 is the lowest and returns the firs row, where that number is found to the index which then returns the correct result.